# Late time behaviour of the Alcubierrie warp drive metric

Tags: general-relativity, metric-tensor, warp-drives

The Alcubeierrie Warp Drive metric looks like $$ds^2 = -dt^2+(dx-Xdt)^2+dy^2+dz^2$$ where $X = v_s(t)f(r_s)$ and $r_s = [(x-x_s(t))^2+y^2+z^2]^{1/2}$. Now, $f(r_s) \approx 1 \quad 0 < r < R$  and
$f(r_s) \approx 0 \quad r_s > R$. Obviously, this metric is time dependent. However, I would like to study the late time behaviour of this metric i.e. $t\to \infty$. What is the best way to take this limit?

Answer (score 2):

That is an interesting question. You first need to solve Einstein equations, find a solution for the shift vector, and analyze its validity limits. You may need to impose boundary conditions to make the solutions physical. One necessary condition is that the warp drive metric should be asymptotically flat, so the shift vector should vanish in such limits, which means you can not sustain a warp bubble indefinitely.

Comment: Right, seems for this one needs infinite negative energy, which is unphysical.

Comment: You think you can explain what the late-time behaviour here looks like?

Comment: This late-time behavior is not unbounded; some constant value must limit it. You must find this when solving Einstein equations and defining physical boundary conditions. Keeping the warp bubble "on" requires vast amounts of negative energy. Instead of $t\to\infty$, consider finding a $t = t_q$, analogous to a half-life capacitor discharge.